# Excel conditional formatting that returns a value

Tags: excel, if-statement, formatting, pivot, conditional-statements

I am currently working on an excel project. I came across this specific issue where if cell A1=" Achieved" then cell A2 = "1" else cell A2=" 0". My question is can it be done without using the If Else statement? I tried using the If Else statement but with formula I cannot get the sum total of the column.

[image: Excel value form]

Comment: Is there a way to do it with VBA then get the total as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
= --(A2="Achieved")

Comment: Note that the double negation (--) changes a TRUE result to 1, and a FALSE result to 0.

Comment: What have you've tried with vba? Perhaps we can modify your code. The formula above was created just for a cell, not for vba. What are you trying to do with vba?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to find the answer it using the change selection in VBA. Now I would like to get the Sum of Cell B2. I found it hard using the selectionchange so that the result will automatically show

Comment: It may be best to ask a new question and include the code you have so far.